# C# SOAP: The specified type was not recognized: name='arrayList'

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a client application in **C#** which is calling some methods from external SOAP service. To work with this service I have generated the proxy class from service WSDL.
Everything is working fine except one operation.
When I'm trying to call this operation it's throwing me **CommunicationException** with the following message:

```
Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'my-operation-name'
```

The **InnerException** is the following:

```
The specified type was not recognized: name='arrayList',
namespace='http://www.oracle.com/webservices/internal/literal', at <validationErrors
xmlns='http://view.label.com/types/'>.
```

I found the description of this element at WSDL file:

```
<element name="validationErrors" type="ns1:list" nillable="true" />
```

but I can't see any references to **arrayList** datatype.

This is the response from service:

```
    <env:Envelope
     xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ns0="http://view.label.com/"
     xmlns:ns1="http://view.label.com/types/"
     xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/webservices/internal/literal">
   <env:Body>
     <ns0:getLabelResponseElement>
     <ns0:result>
     <ns1:statusMessage>Error while reading xml label request.</ns1:statusMessage>
     <ns1:requestId/>
     <ns1:payload/>
     <ns1:labelId/>
     <ns1:status>Error</ns1:status>
     <ns1:validationErrors
       xsi:type="ns2:list"
       xsi:nil="1"/>
     <ns1:statusCode>LabelAssembler_03</ns1:statusCode>
    </ns0:result>
     </ns0:getLabelResponseElement>
    </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

Can you please point me to the possible source of this issue? If it's a problem at my client application part or it's a problem of compatibility because the service is written in Java and my client app in C#?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the SOAP response from the webservice?

Comment: I have added the example of response.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - the proxy class which was generated using **svcutil.exe** generate strange type for one of the members of response objects:

```
private list validationErrorsField;
```

which is:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.oracle.com/webservices/internal/literal")]
public partial class list : collection
{
}
```

and collection is:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(list))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.oracle.com/webservices/internal/literal")]
public partial class collection
{

    private object[] itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("item", Order=0)]
    public object[] item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

so I just changed this problematic type to **string[]** and everything is working now.